# incorporating subprocess into an existing script

Tags: python, subprocess

I have an existing python script, which I'd like to now revise to have more threads (subprocesses) running. For the purpose of this example, let's say revised to run 3 threads at the same time.

Incidentally the script is nothing more than generating a client request to a web server and measuring the response time.

```
#!/usr/bin/python26

from library.rpc.client import EllisClient

ec = EllisClient(ellis_user='fred', ellis_pass='flintstone')
params={'domain_name':'alestel.com','mig_name':'terramexico2'}


def test_response():
    L = []
    L = ec.get_full_domain(params)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from timeit import Timer

    t = Timer("test_response()", "from __main__ import test_response")
    print t.timeit(number=10)
```

As a relative noob, the documentation isn't quite clear to me. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Note that a (sub)process is not the same as a thread...

Comment: If you want to use subprocesses almost as if they were threads, use the `multiprocessing` module. (The `subprocess` module is for running other programs, not for parallelizing your own program.)

Answer (score 0):

If you want explicit control over the processes you're running, you want [`multiprocessing.Process`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#the-process-class):

```
def test_3_parallel_responses():
    procs = [multiprocess.Process(target=test_response) for _ in range(3)]
    for proc in procs:
        proc.start()
    for proc in procs:
        proc.join()
```

That's all there is to it.

There are various differences between threads and processes, but the big one is that you don't get to implicitly share values between processes; you have to pass them around (through the startup `args` and return value, or through a `Queue`, or some external means like a socket or pipe) or explicitly share them (through a `Value` or `Array`, or some external means like an file).

For a more realistic use case, you usually don't want to directly control what the processes are doing; you want to create a pool of processes, and just queue up jobs to get done by whichever process is free next. For that, you want either [`multiprocessing.Pool`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool) or [`concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#processpoolexecutor). The latter is a bit simpler, but requires Python 3.2 or a third-party library, so I'll show the former:

```
def test_3_pooled_responses():
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(3)
    for i in range(3):
        pool.apply(test_response)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

More commonly, you want to actually pass parameters to the function. In the simplest case, this actually makes things even simpler—if you can write the sequential version as a list comprehension or `map` call, you can write the parallel version as a `pool.map` call. Let's say you had a `test_response(host)` call that returns some value, and you wanted to run it on `host1`, `host2`, and `host3`:

```
def test_3_pooled_responses():
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(3)
    responses = pool.map(test_response, ['host1', 'host2', 'host3'])
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Comment: thanks for this information and examples, as it was very helpful